# Sending emails in Pine (Alpine) with underline, emphasis

Tags: formatting, email-client, alpine-mail, underlining

I would like to send emails via Pine (Alpine) but with correct style usage, for instance, underlining book names, etc. How can I create emails in Pine using underline, emphasis, etc. (This can include a variety of receivers of such emails ranging from other Pine users to Outlook to Gmail).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pine/Alpine does not support composing messages in HTML (which is the only rich text format supported for email nowadays).

---

In plain-text media (IRC, non-HTML email), it is very common to use `_` and `*` to denote emphasis. `_word_` can be interpreted as either italic or underlined, and `*word*` usually means bold text. Sometimes, `/word/` is used for italics.

Some mail readers even detect such markup and format text accordingly; an example is Thunderbird. This website does so too.

Comment: Also **Gnus** support emphasis marks...